# Get Image by Class and Click using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get all images from the image class profile_view_img_5087188 but there are multiple classes "profile_view_img_xxxxxx" in the page source and fewer from them containing the same url of an image let says that classes containing image

```
http://i.imgur.com/oraB49H.png
```

and I want to click if the above image url found

```
<head><style type="text/css">.profile_view_img_5087188 { background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/oraB49H.png'); }</style></head>



<a class="cursor earn_pages_button profile_view_img_5087188" onclick="startlink52efa('newlookskincenter','follow','99218',16837);imageWin('http://instagram.com/newlookskincenter','Instagram','99218','newlookskincenter','qFVnV5xlY2OJaW4','1015','500','follow',16837)"></a>
```

here is my code but doesn't work

```
            like_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > span > a")
            for links in like_button:
                    if "http://i.imgur.com/oraB49H.png" in link.get_attribute('href'):
                            links.click()
```

Comment: I am not seeing any `href` attribute in above provided tag, can you add some more html which help to clarify more

Comment: the image source is in the  style sheet 

<head>
<style type="text/css">..profile_view_img_5087188 { background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/oraB49H.png'); }</style></head>

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all the `<a>` tags which have classname `profile_view_img_5087188`  the number is different. So get all tag using  below xpath :

```
like_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'profile_view_img')]")
```

Then loop through in all links and find your image url in

```
for links in like_button:
if "http://instagram.com/newlookskincenter" in link.get_attribute('onclick'):
  links.click()
```

Note : Please make sure you are using correct string comparison as I'm not much aware with python syntax

Comment: @Bostan, try this answer and let me know if having any issue

Comment: @Bostan continue discussion on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139671/get-image-by-class-and-click-using-selenium-python